# Question regarding complex Log and its properties

Tags: complex-analysis

I have principal log which I will denote with Log. Want someone to look over my reasoning.

I think that $Log(1/z) \not= -Log(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My thinking is that if $z$ is on the branch cut in our case at $\pi $ then $Log(1/z) \not= -Log(z)$. However as long as we are not on the branch cut then the preperty $Log(1/z) = -Log(z)$ holds. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Doesn't this fail at $z=e$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I think the wording is a little weird.  I think the OP is saying that $\exists z \in \mathbb{C}: Log\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \neq -Log(z)$ (assuming a particular branch cut).

Comment: Yes it should not be true for the typical branch cut $-\pi <\theta \leq \pi$.